# Nodejs Express EJS Como pasar parametros por 'router' a un menu template que esta en todas las vistas

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs

Buneas quisiera tener un **menubar** disponible en todas mis vistas, para ello uso:

```
 <!--MENU BAR-->
<%- include ./partials/menubar %>
```

Lo que pasa que lo tengo en una estructura de templates de la siguiente manera :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
    <!--MENU BAR-->
    <%- include ./partials/menubar %>

    <!-- CUERPO PAGINA -->
    <div class="container">
        <%-  body    %>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body>

</html>
```

El **menubar** es el siguiente:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Inicio</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Personajes
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                <% for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++) { %>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="personajes">Personaje <%= i %></a>
                <% } %>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Lo que pretendo es que, de alguna manera la barra de menu haga un **for** de los objetos que le pase y siempre este el **combobox dropdown** con una lista de nombres de los personajes. Mi problema es que si mi menu se incrusta en las demas paginas... ¿Como puedo hacer que siempre lleve la memoria de sus datos? Es decir que sepa siempre, independientemente de donde este implementando el menu sus datos como el de los personjes y tal, porque cuando vaya por ejemplo a `'/inicio/'` a lo mejor los reconoce pero si voy a `'/personajes/getall'` ya no.

**ROUTINGS..**

**routes/index.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const routes = express.Router();


    routes.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('inicio')
    });

    module.exports = routes;
```

**routes/personajes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = express.Router();
const Personaje = require("../models/personajes")();

routes.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("personajes" );
});

routes.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const {
    nombre,
    apellidos,
    profesion_estudios,
    fecha_nacimiento,
    descripcion,
    actor
  } = req.body;

  var newPersonaje = {
    nombre,
    apellidos,
    profesion_estudios,
    fecha_nacimiento,
    descripcion,
    actor
  };

  Personaje.create(newPersonaje)
    .then(personaje => {
      res.send({
        message: "Personaje guardado correctamente !!"
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({
        message: "Error al guardar el personaje nuevo !!"
      });
    });
});

routes.get("/getall", (req, res) => {
  Personaje.find()
    .then(personajes => {
      res.send(personajes);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

routes.get("/get/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Personaje.findById(id)
    .then(personaje => {
      res.render('personajes',{
          personaje:personaje
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({
        message: "Error al encontrar personaje con id ",
        id
      });
    });
});

routes.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  Personaje.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    .then(personaje => {
      res.send({
        message: `Personaje borrado`
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send({
        message: "Error al borrar"
      });
    });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: para todas las peticiones debes mandar datos desde backend